# Design pattern for surrounding code in start, complete and fail methods

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Suppose I have various arbitrary sections of code to run, but before each section, I have to run a `Start()` method and then after each section I need to run a `Complete()` method. However, if an exception is thrown in the code section, I want to run a `Fail(string message)` method instead of `Complete()`. Is there a design pattern that elegantly encapsulates this to make it neat and easily repeatable?

For example, let's say I have a type called `Thing` that contains a `Start()` method that adds a row to a logging db table to reflect that a task is in progress, a `Complete()` method that changes that row to reflect that the task finished and a `Fail(string message)` method that changes the row to reflect that the task failed. These are just examples though, they could be doing any set-up and tidy up type tasks.

The naive implementation might be simply to call those methods manually:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    var thing = new Thing();
    thing.Start();
    try
    {
        DoImportantStuff();
        thing.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        thing.Fail(e.Message);
    }
}
```

But if I'm going to have to repeat this in a lot of different places, it ends up creating quite a lot of duplication and it might be easy to forget to call `Complete` or mess this up in some subtle way.

In C#, there's the `using` pattern, which provides a good way of encapsulating most of this. For example, if my `Thing` type looked like this:

```
public class Thing : IDisposable
{
    public Thing(){
        Start();
    }

    private void Start() { /* start */ }
    private void Complete() { /* complete */ }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Complete();
    }
}
```

My `DoStuff()` method could now be simplified to this:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    using(new Thing())
    {
        DoImportantStuff();
    }
}
```

Which is much nicer. But it doesn't allow me to call `Fail` instead of `Complete` if an exception is thrown because (I think!) the `Dispose` method is essentially called in a `Finally` block.

I have thought of having a `try/catch` inside the `using` block and then setting a `thing.HasFailed` flag inside the `catch` block and then using that in the `Dispose` method to decide whether to `Complete` or `Fail`. But that seems a bit fiddly and I'd like the consumer of `Thing` to have to do as little as possible to make it work correctly.

So is there a design pattern that encapsulates what I want to do and avoids the need to manually write a `try\catch` each time?

Comment: Have a look at Aspect Oriented programming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Look like you could define your entry/error/leave methods as join points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have a `Thing` like this:

```
public class Thing 
{
  private void Start() { /* start */ }
  private void Complete() { /* complete */ }
  private void Fail(string message) {}

  public void DoAction(Action action)
  {
      this.Start();
      try 
      {
        action();
        this.Complete();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        this.Fail(e.Message);
      }

  }
}
```

And Use it like this:

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
thing.DoAction(this.DoStuff);
```

Comment: This is actually not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: While maybe this isn't a design pattern as such, I think this is easily the most elegant solution in a language with first class functions so I've marked it as accepted. In a language without function passing, I guess the Template method pattern would be the best option

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is called "template method". You can find your implementation under the title "aspect oriented programming".
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288717(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: If you're going to link to something, please include a code example in your actual answer, as links can expire.

Comment: Good call mentioning the Template Method pattern although I'm not sure the link is that useful since it doesn't explicitely discuss the Template pattern and is a bit bogged down in web service specifics. The wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) offers a better summary: "In software engineering, the template method pattern is a behavioral design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in an operation, deferring some steps to subclasses. It lets one redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure"

Answer (score 0):

Using [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

```
public class Thing : IDisposable
{
    private void Start() { /* start */ }
    private void Complete() { /* complete */ }
    private void Fail(string _szMessage) {/* fail */}

    public delegate void ProcessClientStuff();

    private ProcessClientStuff m_delegateClientStuff;

    public Thing(ProcessClientStuff _delegateClientStuff) {m_delegateClientStuff = _delegateClientStuff}

    public void Dostuff()
    {
        Start();

        try
        {
            m_delegateClientStuff();
            Complete();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Fail(e.Message);
        }
    }    
}


void ClientStuff()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}

Thing oClientStuffProcessor = new Thing(ClientStuff);
oClientStuffProcessor.Dostuff();
```